# Symfony 5.4 ApiPlatform POST request body is always empty

Tags: php, symfony

Been struggling for 4 hours.

Unfortunately, Symfony docs only contains most basic examples and googling only gives solutions for super-old versions.

I have created an API endpoint with Symfony 5.4 which works perfectly via Postman.

However, trying to cover it with a test using `ApiPlatform`'s `ApiTestCase` ends up with request being totally empty as it reaches the endpoint.

`var_dump($request->request);` at the start of the endpoint code gives me (does not happen with Postman)

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag)#109 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

when trying to run this test:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;

class PropertyTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testCreatePropertyValidNoParent(): void
    {
        $name = 'Test Property ' . uniqid();

        $payload = [];
        $payload['name'] = $name;

        $response = static::createClient()->request(
            'POST',
            '/api/property',
            [
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
                'json'    => $payload
            ]
        );

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}
```

Replacing `body` with `json` produced the same result

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Was able to work arounb the issue by passing `parameters` like that:

```
$response = static::createClient()->request(
            'POST',
            '/api/property',
            [
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
                'body'    => $payload,
                'extra' => [
                    'parameters' => $payload
                ]
            ]
        );
```

which seems like a hack though...

Comment: If everything works with a common request, but not with one crafted through your test case, what's the difference between them?

Comment: Looks like `vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Test/Client.php` populates the request body and params differently. Don't know if it's a bug or a known issue. Probably the latter, since they have no POST examples in their docs.

Comment: why do you bother setting the content-type? I would trust in the defaults when using POST. what happens, when you drop the headers entirely? like here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data

Comment: the same thing. I just added this header to make request similar to Postman request. The copy-paste you are seeing is just a snapshot of one of my many attempts